# I forgot the MEMO in a transaction

Tags: memo

I need help guys i forget to include the MEMO in a transaction from BlockChain to Coinbase[image: Transaction]. What can i do?
Thank You

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing Stellar can do. The memo is used by Coinbase to associate the transaction to your account; you can't recall the transaction, and you can't update the memo after submission. You'll have to talk to Coinbase to get the funds to connect to the correct Coinbase account.

Comment: Also see: https://medium.com/stellar-community/help-i-forgot-my-stellar-memo-d62b3cc9c2f7