# Can I get help recovering my XLM that sent to the StellarChain.io Testnet?

Tags: transactions

In my attempt to send my XLM from Bittrex to pro.coinbase, the tokens were sent to the StellarChain.io Testnet. How can I recover them? I've included the following information about the transaction. Can anyone please help me? I'd be very thankful!

```
Payment: 056a1c8ee149ac95fd6f52f9d4f475fa8e0ac6acbddbed7719ee65c706e0074e
GB6YPGW5JFMMP2QB2USQ33EUWTXVL4ZT5ITUNCY3YKVWOJPP57CANOF3GDQP2KPQGKIHYJGXNUIYOMHARUARCA7DJT5FO2FFOOKY3B2WSQHG4W37
XLM37947.0174635
Summary
Created at: 2020-11-25 14:29:16 · 2 months ago
Fee:    0.00005010 XLM
Ledger: 32777011
Other
Paging Token:   140776190305779712
Sequence:   2394452857809001
Memo text:  Transf to CoinBasePro
Signatures:
- AciDBqxRvfEJiMziGUAZXplRv4yoOksGsNaV2g/fumeQmFuu8fxUgRwH5qh2W4tLZFA2i2CIjBwHmc/R/P8qAg==
Donations: GAI3GJ2Q3B35AOZJ36C4ANE3HSS4NK7WI6DNO4ZSHRAX6NG7BMX6VJER
```

Answer (score 1):

The transaction was made on the public network, you can see it here:
https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/tx/056a1c8ee149ac95fd6f52f9d4f475fa8e0ac6acbddbed7719ee65c706e0074e

However, you're supposed to include a MEMO-ID in deposits to Coinbase. You get this MEMO-ID from Coinbase when you do a deposit. What you included "Transf to CoinBasePro" looks like you tried to write a private note, which is not the intention.

Contact Coinbase support and see if they can add the deposit to your Coinbase balance. Unfortunately, since you did this payment directly from Bittrex, it might be hard for you to prove that this is your indeed your transaction. You should try reaching out to them and see if they can help you prove that it was your transaction.

I wish you the best of luck!

See also:

- [I forgot the MEMO in a transaction](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/2468/i-forgot-the-memo-in-a-transaction)
- https://medium.com/stellar-community/help-i-forgot-my-stellar-memo-d62b3cc9c2f7